# Is it valid to return a reference as a reference valid in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int& fun1(int& ref)
{
  ref = 30;
  return ref;
}

int main()
{
  int i = 10;

  i = fun1(i);
  cout << "Value of i:" << i << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:
Value of i:30

Is it valid to return a function argument passed as reference as a function return the same reference?
According to my understanding ref in fun1(int& ref) will have a it's own memory location in the stack and returning the address of ref is invalid.

Comment: That code is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, this is valid. There is no such thing as a reference to a reference in c++, if that is what caused your confusion.

Comment: When you pass a parameter by reference, returning the same reference has no meaning, and so no impact. Reference parameters' value is updated whenever it is updated inside the function, "fun1" in your case.

Answer (score 2):

References act in every way as if they were the original object. This means that taking the address of a reference gives the address of the original object and taking a reference to a reference gives a reference to the original object.

While there exists pointers to pointers, there is no such thing as a reference to a reference.

Take note the assignment in `i = fun1(i);` is redundant. `i` is already `30` in this case. You can simply call `fun1(i);`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  it's fine.  What matters is that the lifetime of the referent is long enough.